# What is correct way to deal with ambiguous typecasting/conversions C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, casting

I have code similar to this:

```
class Pair{
public:
    Pair(const void *blob);
    //...
    int cmp(const std::string &key) const;
    int cmp(const Pair &pair) const;
}
```

Later if I do:

```
Pair p = ...;
p.cmp("Hello");
```

It won't compile, because conversion from `const char *` is ambiguous.

It can be translated to `std::string` and `cmp(std::string)` to be invoked, or...

it can be translated to `Pair` and `cmp(const Pair)` to be invoked.

I can not do constructor `explicit`.

I tried to do:

```
Pair(const char *blob) = deleted;
```

But then I can not construct the class with `nullptr` and I want to be able to do so.

As final solution, I defined following method:

```
int cmp(const char *key) const{
   return cmp( std::string{ key } );
}
```

and it works fine.

Is there better way to deal with such class conversions?

Comment: "But then I can not construct the class with nullptr and I want to be able to do so." - make one of your constructors take `nullptr_t`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your “final solution” looks pretty good to me.  Not constructing a temporary will also help improve performance.  If your strings are known not to contain NUL characters, you can implement the version taking a `std::string` as argument as

```
inline int
cmp(const std::string& s)
{
  return this->cmp(s.c_str());
}
```

which is too simple to worry about.

Making `Pair`'s constructor `explicit` (I assume the “`implicit`” is a typo) sounds a good idea to me, too.  Why can't you do it?

Comment: explicit is typo. I like to be able to do `Pair p = mem_ptr;` Looks nice and clean to me. There is no temporary I use non standard StringRef class.

Comment: With an `explicit` c'tor, you could still write `Pair p {mem_ptr};`.  Looks nicer and cleaner to me.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can make the constructor `explicit`.

```
explicit Pair(const void *blob) { ... }
```

Then,

```
p.cmp("Hello");
```

will resolve to

```
int cmp(const std::string &key) const;
```

Comment: explicit was typo. sorry